# prioritize pushing element to array

Tags: javascript

I have an array with objects as elements. What I did was check if the titles value contains a certain string and it it does push that a new array and log the new array and the process works.

What I want is when pushing to the new array I want to prioritize the string found first to be pushed first.

To explain it better say my array is this:

```
myArr = [{"title": "test hello"}, {"title": "hello test"}, {"title": "test test"}]
```

If my search string is `hello` I want my new array to be this:

```
[{"title": "hello test"}, {"title": "test hello"}]
```

The search string found first will be put first. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```js
const myArr = [{
  "title": "test hello"
}, {
  "title": "hello test"
}, {
  "title": "test test"
}]

const searchValue = 'Hello'

let foundArr = []

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  if (myArr[i].title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
    foundArr.push(myArr[i])
  }
}

//expected output [{"title": "hello test"}, {"title": "test hello"}]
console.log(foundArr)
```

Comment: You probably want to use fuzzy search. fuse.js can be useful. If you want to do this without a library, you can use indexOf and sort by it

Comment: So just finding that word is not enough for you. You need to rank them with specific matching types. (matching earlier in the sentence has higher priority)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you require you could `sort()` the array by the index of the matched string within the value.

Also, you can simplify the logic by using `filter()` to find matches instead of an explicit `for` loop:

```js
const myArr = [
  { title: "test hello" }, 
  { title: "hello test" }, 
  { title: "test test" }, 
  { title: "foo hello test" }
]

const searchValue = 'Hello'.toLowerCase();
let foundArr = myArr
  .filter(o => o.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue))
  .sort((a, b) => a.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) > b.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) ? 1 : -1);

console.log(foundArr)
```

Comment: for some reason its not working on my array take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=RsIrVR4eLd

Comment: Can you save the fiddle and share it? It opens empty fiddle for me

Comment: here is a new fiddle the https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=RsIrVR4eLd

Comment: @Rajesh take a look at the fiddle above. My array is kinda big so make sure to scroll all the was down.

Comment: Seems to me its working fine. You make 1 mistake. Comparison operator should be greater than not less than. For your [reference](https://jsfiddle.net/ze0oLwpy/)

Comment: @Rajesh yeah that was the issue thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `Array.reduce`

#### Logic:

- Loop over values and fetch index of string
- Use index as key and insert it in object
- At the end, delete `"-"` as they are non-matching elements
- Return values of this object's values

```js
const myArr = [{"title": "test hello"}, {"title": "hello test"}, {"title": "test test"}]
const searchValue = 'Hello'

const matches = myArr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const index = item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase())
  acc[index] = item
  return acc
}, {})
delete matches["-1"];
console.log(Object.values(matches))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string member method `indexOf` to acquire the index of a matching pattern. Afterwards filter out any non matching elements.

```js
const myArr = [
  {
    title: "test hello"
  },
  {
    title: "hello test"
  },
  {
    title: "test test"
  }
];

const searchValue = "Hello";

const result = myArr
  .map(({ title }) => {
    var index = title
      .toLocaleLowerCase()
      .indexOf(searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase());

    
    return {
      match: index >= 0,
      index: index,
      title
    };
  })
  .filter(({ match }) => match)
  .sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index);

//expected output [{"title": "hello test"}, {"title": "test hello"}]
console.log(result);
```

On such problems, try not to iterate too often through your arrays.